# java spring boot with Protobuf is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, protobuf-java

I have the following application details, where I am adding protobuf to an existing spring boot application.

pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-format</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Application.java
I have added the formatter as given below in Application.java

```
@Bean
    ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
    }
```

Spring boot version used: `2.6.9`

The below is the API controller

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/reports/process", consumes = "application/x-protobuf")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> processReports(
            @Parameter(description = "Process report data", required = true)
            @RequestBody ReportCollection executionReports) {
```

I have written and generated the `.proto` file for Java (above application)
The same .proto file is used in python and python generated the data and posted to the above API using `application/x-protobuf` in both the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers.

However the Spring boot API that received the payload throws the below exception

```
Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Boolean> com.*.ReportsApiController.processReports(com.*.ReportCollection): Content type 'application/x-protobuf;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

I have been googling for solution and not able to get this fixed, can you please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume protobuf parameters using Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023714/how-to-consume-protobuf-parameters-using-spring-rest)

Comment: I tried this solution, it works fine, but it is returning status code `406` now. Also, it looks like this is applicable for MVC, is it ok to use this for rest API only.